# Bypassing redis @Memoize annotation in Spock unit tests

Tags: grails, redis, spock, memoization

I have a simple method in a Grails service like so:

```
@Memoize(key = 'foo_#{text}', expire = '#{grailsApplication.config.cache.ttl}') 
String createString(String text) {
    return text + ' redis'
}
```

It works as expected in prod, and the Spock unit tests I had for it pass fine without the `@Memoize` annotation.  However, with the annotation, they simply return `null`:

```
void "createString() should create string"() {
    given:
        String text = 'foo'

    when:
        String result = service.createString(text)

    then:
        assert text + ' redis' == result // result is 'null'
}
```

I tried mocking the `redisService`:

```
1 * mockRedisService.memoize(_, _, _) >> someString
```

but that had no effect. I realize I could probably turn this into an integration test, but the method is quite simple and I'd prefer not to override my redis cache data.

How can I make the tests bypass the annotation?

Comment: Can you set TTL `grailsApplication.config.cache.ttl` in the test to zero or negative value? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: @dmahapatro Hm, good idea.  I tried, but no luck.  I'd expect it to fire the code off without relying on redis, if the key hasn't been cached yet, too. I feel like I'm missing something.